# How to use the same shared example and before filter on several RSpec Contexts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, dry, before-filter

I've got a really ugly controller spec that looks like this:

```
describe "GET index" do
  context "when authorized" do
    before(:each) do
      sign_in @user
    end

    ...
  end

  include_examples "when unauthorized"
end

describe "GET show" do
  context "when authorized" do
    before(:each) do
      sign_in @user
    end

    ...
  end

  include_examples "when unauthorized"
end

...
```

Is there any way to move the before filter and shared example out into some kind of common feature of each action? If not, is there any way to DRY this up at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. An example from:https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

```
require "set"

shared_examples "a collection object" do
  describe "<<" do
    it "adds objects to the end of the collection" do
      collection << 1
      collection << 2
      expect(collection.to_a).to match_array([1, 2])
    end
  end
end

describe Array do
  it_behaves_like "a collection object" do
    let(:collection) { Array.new }
  end
end

describe Set do
  it_behaves_like "a collection object" do
    let(:collection) { Set.new }
  end
end
```

I should stress that every test should only test one thing so be careful how you write it.  You can also move shared content to a separate file which the link above shows as well under the shared content tab.

Remember that you want your tests to be readable.  For small bits of code like the before filter and signing in I leave in.  It may not be DRY, but for me it is easier to read the test straight through rather than referring to separate examples or files.  If you have a large test that you are doing multiple times it would be easier to move it out to a separate example or file.

Comment: I don't see how this saves me from putting the `it_behaves_like` line in each description? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: In your example you want to test for the unauthorized section of each page.  Although the code may look the same, you are testing two different things.  I think you are asking if there is a way to bound tests together, which you don't want to do.  Each test should be separate and self contained.  You might have the same line in each test, but that line tests separate parts of your code.

Comment: But shouldn't there be some sort of way to DRY up the code with a line at the top of the file? Something like `include_examples, :only => [:index, :show...]`?

Comment: Test are made to be readable.  When you start extracting outside of the blocks you lose that readability.  You need to keep at least that one line in the block so you know what is being executed in that particular block.

Comment: Let's say you were able to write that line of code and take it out of your test block.  You are able to make the test work and continue with your project.  Then a year later and hundreds of tests later you do something to make the old test fail.  From your logs you see that the test on line 438 failed and you look at the block and try to debug. Everything in the block looks fine and should work. But part of your code is completely separate from that block and you have no idea that it is being run.  That becomes a huge problem.

Comment: Being DRY here is more like being DRY in your views.  You can extract a repeatable part of your view like user stats to a shared partial, but you still need to place a line of code in each page telling Rails to render that shared file.

Comment: I guess so, but something about it just doesn't feel right to me. I mean, I don't have to add a line to every action in a controller to include a before block, and before blocks don't really hurt readability. I don't see how testing something that's going to be reused on basically everything, like authorization, with a single line at the top of the file hurts readability. Oh well, I guess this is just my opinion.